# How to validate specific word in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rails-activerecord

I'd like to validate a specific words in my book.rb models words:

book_name = "Pencil", "Paper", "Toy"

if the user does not enter any of those fields then it will be invalid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following AR validation
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#inclusion

```
 validates :book_name, inclusion: { in: %w(Pencil Paper Toy) }
```

Comment: Great, it's what I was looking for. More people like you: D thanks for your time